# AngularJS issues with compiler attribute in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm learning AngularJS and I'm training for how to build a reusable directive.

The problem is that it works with an array with one element, but not with two or more.

The HTML tag is just: `<breadcrumb></breadcrumb>` which in case, render as expected. But, I need to do manually what "replace:true" would do.

The error is: **parent is null**.

I exhausted all Google searches looking for an example.

But my case is peculiar, because there is an `<inner ng-repeat>` inside `<breadcrumb>` which is an another inner-directive instead an normal tag, that's why replace doesn't work and I need to do manually.

There is a problem related to "dynamic template load..."

OBS: I tried to do in both "link:" and "compile:" the logic, same error...

---

I could make the code work, but, I'm unable to remove `<inner>` tag as `transclude` would do automatic.

Now the output is almost perfect, and I just need to remove the `<inner>`, but no luck until now. I tried to replace the element tag, but still no luck.

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">

    <!-- I want to remove this <inner> and leave <li> alone! -->
    <inner data-ng-repeat="_item in items track by $index" class="ng-scope">
        <li class="ng-scope"><a href="#" class="ng-binding">1</a>
        </li>
    </inner>

    <!-- remove for clarity -->
</ul>
```

> 

```
var myModule = angular.module("myModule", []);

myModule.directive('breadcrumb', function($timeout) {

    "use strict";

    var directiveDefinitionObject = {
        template: '<ul class="breadcrumb"><inner data-ng-repeat="_item in items track by $index"></inner></ul>',
        replace: true,
        // transclude: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        controller: ["$scope", "$element", "$attrs", "$transclude", controller],
        link: ["scope", "iElement", "iAttrs", link]
    };

    function link(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        scope.addNewItem = function(new_item) {
            scope._push(new_item);
        }
    }

    function controller($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude) {
        $scope.items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

        $scope._push = function(item) {
            $scope.items.push(item);
        };

        $scope._pop = function() {
            $scope.items.pop();
        };

        $scope.is_last = function(item) {
            return $scope.items.indexOf(item) == ($scope.items.length - 1);
        }
    }

    return directiveDefinitionObject;
});

myModule.directive("inner", ["$compile",
    function($compile) {

        "use strict";

        function getItemTemplate(index) {
            return '<li><a href="#">{{ _item }}</a></li>';
        }

        return {
            require: "^breadcrumb",
            restrict: "E",
            compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs)
            {
                return function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs)
                {
                    iElement.html(getItemTemplate(0));

                    $compile(iElement.contents())(scope);
                };
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle or plunkr to show this in action.

Comment: I tried this out with a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/SwpzE/ and it appears the issue is probably happening because your code is replacing the element that has the ng-repeat directive on it, then the next time it tries to do the same thing that element is already replaced.  I think you just need to re-think how to do this a bit.

Comment: @shaunhusain Good point. I will check this ng-repeat overwrite. Btw, I have just updated the code. But still I cannot get rid of `<inner>` tag to be replaced by the template (which will be dynamic).

Comment: @shaunhusain I guess you're right about my removal of ng-repeat. That's why it fails on the second element array. Now I just need to learn how to work around this.

Comment: You just need to set 'replace: true' at your inner directive  too.

Comment: @CaioToOn Nops... when you use compile: fn(), replace true/false makes no difference. Believe me, I tried "everything".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove the compile function of yours in `inner` directive and set `replace: true`, because it's just mocking the default behavior of `replace`, as you stated. So you `inner` directive would become:

```js
myModule.directive("inner", ["$compile",
  function($compile) {

    "use strict";

    return {
      replace: true
      require: "^breadcrumb",
      restrict: "E",
      template: '<li><a href="#">{{ _item }}</a></li>'
    };
  }
]);
```

But you have a problem that your `items` array is defined into your `breadcrumb` directive, what is wrong and will not let you make it reusable. You could bind it at `scope` definition with something like this:

```html
<breadcrumb items="someItemsArrayFromParentScope"></breadcrumb>
```

```js
...directive('breadcrumb', function() {
   ...

   return {
     ...
     scope: {
       items: '='
     }
   }
});
```

This would create a two directional binding between the array from parent and internal widget scope. But going further, you might want to let the user define the inner elements of the `breadcrumb`, it would be as following:

```js
myModule.directive('breadcrumb', function($timeout) {
  var directiveDefinitionObject = {
    template: '<ul class="breadcrumb" ng-transclude></ul>',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    controller: ["$scope", "$element", "$attrs", "$transclude", controller]
  };

  function controller($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude) {
    $scope.addNewItem = function(new_item) {
        $scope._push(new_item);
    }

    $scope._push = function(item) {
        $scope.items.push(item);
    };

    $scope._pop = function() {
        $scope.items.pop();
    };

    $scope.is_last = function(item) {
        return $scope.items.indexOf(item) == ($scope.items.length - 1);
    }
  }

  return directiveDefinitionObject;
});

myModule.directive("inner", function($compile) {
    return {
        require: "^breadcrumb",
        restrict: "E",
        template: '<li><a href="#" ng-transclude></a></li>',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true
    };
  }
);
```

And in your html you would come with:

```html
<breadcrumb>
  <inner ng-repeat="item in items"><i>{{item}}</i></inner>
</breacrumb>
```

The trick is the `ng-transclude` directive inside the templates. It just get the contents of the element and "move it" to inside the element marked with `ng-transclude` and link it against the parent scope, what is awesome, as you can have dynamic naming for the items that would be based on parent scope. The `items` of the `ng-repeat`, for example, would be defined in the parent scope, as expected. This is the preferred way, and you would even get the possibility of use different inner templates (as I did with the `<i>` tag). You would even be able to not use an `ng-repeat` and hardcode the `inner` elements, if it's the case:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<breadcrumb>
  <inner>First Path</inner>
  <inner>Second Path: {{someParentScopeVariable}}</inner>
</breacrumb>
```

Here is a working [Plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8JPW4w4WhrnU82rY2Az4?p=preview).

Comment: Now I make it work thanks to you. I never imagined angular works that way. Removing compile callback was wonderful.

Comment: Yes, Angular has many tricks we're not used with a jQuery background. Take a look at this [docs page](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), it's a very good source of info. The text is not that simple, it could be better, but it will explain a lot.

Comment: Could you tell me if it would make more sense doing the get/set methods in controller level instead $scope? Inside controller this._push(item) instead $scope._push(item).

Comment: Yes, it does. Just as `ng-model` does. You are creating a `breadrumb` controller API. And you can't assume `inner`'s scope will be the same as `breadcrumb`'s, as you can create other directive (different from `inner`) that would interact with `breadcrumb` but demand isolated scope.

Comment: I found another way. Check my answer below, maybe you make some opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to rebuilt it.

I've learnt a lot since my first attempt.

The solution was simplified because the dynamic template is rubbish to handle, because *ng-repeat* does not redraw the entire array. So, I did it my own way and it was a clean solution.

Comment: The Plnker link is broken ("Not found") - removed for now.

Comment: @PeterMortensen it does work for me. I was redirected to: https://plnkr.co/edit/8JPW4w4WhrnU82rY2Az4?p=preview&preview